# Why does the width of my web page extend beyond my viewport?

Tags: html, css, width, viewport, svelte

I have this web page. All the content of the web page is within the size of my desktop's view port. However, the width of the page still goes beyond the view port. I even tried putting margin and padding at 0 but nothing worked. It also looks especially awkward in mobile view. How do I fix that?

Below is the code:

```css
:root {
--main-color:#ff9955ff;
--secondary-color:yellow;
--dark-color:#444;
--light-color:#fafafa;
}
body {
font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
background: var(--light-color);
color: var(--dark-color);
text-align: justify;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
align-items: center;
padding: 10px;
font-size: 18px;
}

::selection {
    background: var(--main-color);
    color: var(--light-color);
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: var(--dark-color);
}
input {
box-sizing: border-box;
}

.box {
    background: red;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
.center-text {
    text-align: center;
}
.columns-two, .columns-three, .columns-four, .columns-six {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    gap: 30px;
}
.columns-two div {
    width: clamp(480px, 480px, 100%);
}
.columns-three div {
    width: clamp(200px, calc((1000px - (30px * 2)) / 3), 100%);
}
.columns-four div {
    width: calc((1000px - (30px * 3)) / 4);
}
.columns-six div {
    width: calc((1000px - (30px * 5)) / 6);
}
.horizontal {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    gap: 20px;
}

.max-height {
    min-height: 100vh;
}
.half-height {
    min-height: calc(100vh / 2);
}
.max-width {
    width: clamp(200px, 90vw, 1000px);
}
.vertical {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.wrap {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

/* header */
.header {
    height: 70px;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.title {
    height: 100%;
}
.title img {
    height: 100%;
    width: clamp(0px,250px,60%);
}
.nav-toggle-checkbox, .nav-toggle-spans {
    position: fixed;
    top: 2.5%;
    right: -100vw;
    height: clamp(10px,80px,20vw);
    width: clamp(10px,80px,20vw);
}
.nav-toggle-checkbox {
    opacity: 0;
}
.nav-toggle-spans span {
    height: 20%;
    background: var(--main-color);
    margin: 10% 0;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    z-index: 2;
    transition: 400ms;
}
.navbar {
    display: flex;
    gap: 2.5px;
    transition: 300ms;
}
.navbar a {
    margin: 5px;
}

/* footer */
footer {
    background: var(--main-color);
    width: 100vw;
    padding: 20px 0;
    text-align: center;
}
.socials {
    gap: 10px;
}
footer img {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
}


@media screen and (max-width:700px) {
    .nav-toggle-checkbox, .nav-toggle-spans {
        right: 5%;
        transition: 400ms;
    }
    .nav-toggle-spans {
        z-index: 2;
    }
    .nav-toggle-checkbox {
        z-index: 3;
    }
    .nav-toggle-checkbox:checked ~ .nav-toggle-spans span {
        background: var(--light-color);
        transition: 400ms;
    }
    .nav-toggle-checkbox:checked ~ .nav-toggle-spans .nav-span-one {
        position: relative;
        top: 30%; /* Changed from 100% */
        transform: rotate(45deg);
        transition: 400ms;
    }
    .nav-toggle-checkbox:checked ~ .nav-toggle-spans .nav-span-two {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    .nav-toggle-checkbox:checked ~ .nav-toggle-spans .nav-span-three {
        position: relative;
        top: -30%;
        transform: rotate(-45deg);
        transition: 400ms;
    }
    .navbar, .nav-toggle-checkbox:not(:checked) ~ .navbar {
        position:fixed;
        top: 0;
        right: -100vh;
        height: 100%;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content:flex-start;
        background: var(--main-color);
        opacity: 90%;
        border-left: 4px solid var(--secondary-color);
        padding: 150px 5% 0 50px;
        z-index: 1;
        transition: 400ms;
    }
    .nav-toggle-checkbox:checked ~ .navbar {
        right: 0;
        transition: 400ms;
    }
    .nav-toggle-checkbox:checked ~ .navbar a {
        color: var(--light-color);
        text-align: right;
        font-size: 1.25em;
    }
}
```

```html
<body tabindex="-1">
  <div id="svelte">

    <body>
      <div class="max-width">
        <header class="header horizontal">
          <div class="title"><img loading="lazy" src="./logo-title.svg" alt="Title"></div> <input type="checkbox" class="nav-toggle-checkbox">
          <div class="nav-toggle-spans"><span class="nav-span-one"></span> <span class="nav-span-two"></span> <span class="nav-span-three"></span></div>
          <nav class="navbar"><a href="/">Home</a> <a href="elements">Elements</a> <a href="services">Services</a> <a href="contact">Contact</a></nav>
        </header>
        <!--<Header>-->

        <head>
          <title>Home - CSS Templates</title>
        </head>
        <section class="vertical">
          <h2>2 Columns</h2>
          <div class="wrap columns-two">
            <div>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
                tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Amet luctus
                venenatis lectus magna fringilla urna porttitor rhoncus dolor. Nisi quis
                eleifend quam adipiscing vitae proin sagittis nisl. Ipsum dolor sit amet
                consectetur adipiscing. Eu consequat ac felis donec et odio pellentesque
                diam. Volutpat commodo sed egestas egestas fringilla phasellus faucibus
                scelerisque. Sem et tortor consequat id porta nibh venenatis cras. Sed
                faucibus turpis in eu mi bibendum neque egestas congue. Etiam non quam
                lacus suspendisse faucibus interdum posuere lorem. Malesuada fames ac
                turpis egestas maecenas pharetra. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
                consectetur. Ut enim blandit volutpat maecenas volutpat blandit aliquam
                etiam erat. Id aliquet risus feugiat in ante metus.</p>
            </div>
            <div>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
                tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Amet luctus
                venenatis lectus magna fringilla urna porttitor rhoncus dolor. Nisi quis
                eleifend quam adipiscing vitae proin sagittis nisl. Ipsum dolor sit amet
                consectetur adipiscing. Eu consequat ac felis donec et odio pellentesque
                diam. Volutpat commodo sed egestas egestas fringilla phasellus faucibus
                scelerisque. Sem et tortor consequat id porta nibh venenatis cras. Sed
                faucibus turpis in eu mi bibendum neque egestas congue. Etiam non quam
                lacus suspendisse faucibus interdum posuere lorem. Malesuada fames ac
                turpis egestas maecenas pharetra. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
                consectetur. Ut enim blandit volutpat maecenas volutpat blandit aliquam
                etiam erat. Id aliquet risus feugiat in ante metus.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
        <!--<ColumnsTwo>-->
        <section class="vertical max-height">
          <h2>3 Columns</h2>
          <div class="wrap columns-three">
            <div>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
                tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Amet luctus
                venenatis lectus magna fringilla urna porttitor rhoncus dolor. Nisi quis
                eleifend quam adipiscing vitae proin sagittis nisl. Ipsum dolor sit amet
                consectetur adipiscing. Eu consequat ac felis donec et odio pellentesque
                diam. Volutpat commodo sed egestas egestas fringilla phasellus faucibus
                scelerisque. Sem et tortor consequat id porta nibh venenatis cras. Sed
                faucibus turpis in eu mi bibendum neque egestas congue.</p>
            </div>
            <div>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
                tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Amet luctus
                venenatis lectus magna fringilla urna porttitor rhoncus dolor. Nisi quis
                eleifend quam adipiscing vitae proin sagittis nisl. Ipsum dolor sit amet
                consectetur adipiscing. Eu consequat ac felis donec et odio pellentesque
                diam. Volutpat commodo sed egestas egestas fringilla phasellus faucibus
                scelerisque. Sem et tortor consequat id porta nibh venenatis cras. Sed
                faucibus turpis in eu mi bibendum neque egestas congue.</p>
            </div>
            <div>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
                tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Amet luctus
                venenatis lectus magna fringilla urna porttitor rhoncus dolor. Nisi quis
                eleifend quam adipiscing vitae proin sagittis nisl. Ipsum dolor sit amet
                consectetur adipiscing. Eu consequat ac felis donec et odio pellentesque
                diam. Volutpat commodo sed egestas egestas fringilla phasellus faucibus
                scelerisque. Sem et tortor consequat id porta nibh venenatis cras. Sed
                faucibus turpis in eu mi bibendum neque egestas congue.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
        <!--<ColumnsThree>-->
        <section class="vertical">
          <hr>
          <h2>4 Columns</h2>
          <div class="wrap columns-four">
            <div class="box"></div>
            <div class="box"></div>
            <div class="box"></div>
            <div class="box"></div>
          </div>
          <hr>
        </section>
        <!--<ColumnsFour>-->
        <section class="vertical">
          <hr>
          <h2>6 Columns</h2>
          <div class="wrap columns-six">
            <div class="box"></div>
            <div class="box"></div>
            <div class="box"></div>
            <div class="box"></div>
            <div class="box"></div>
            <div class="box"></div>
          </div>
          <hr>
        </section>
        <!--<ColumnsSix>-->
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
          incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Amet luctus venenatis lectus
          magna fringilla urna porttitor rhoncus dolor. Nisi quis eleifend quam
          adipiscing vitae proin sagittis nisl. Ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur
          adipiscing. Eu consequat ac felis donec et odio pellentesque diam. Volutpat
          commodo sed egestas egestas fringilla phasellus faucibus scelerisque. Sem et
          tortor consequat id porta nibh venenatis cras. Sed faucibus turpis in eu mi
          bibendum neque egestas congue. Etiam non quam lacus suspendisse faucibus
          interdum posuere lorem. Malesuada fames ac turpis egestas maecenas pharetra.
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur. Ut enim blandit volutpat maecenas
          volutpat blandit aliquam etiam erat. Id aliquet risus feugiat in ante metus.</p>
      <footer>
        <p class="socials"><a href="www.facebook.com" target="_blank"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/fb/Facebook_icon_2013.svg" alt="facebook"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
          <a href="www.facebook.com" target="_blank"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/fb/Facebook_icon_2013.svg" alt="facebook"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
          <a href="www.facebook.com" target="_blank"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/fb/Facebook_icon_2013.svg" alt="facebook"></a></p>
        <p>This website was designed by <a href="google.com">Name</a></p>
      </footer>
    </body>
    <div id="svelte-announcer" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true" class="s-jHz34e3aRDB7"></div>
  </div>


</body>
```

Comment: Please create a jsfiddle or codepen example, this is a css issue and not svelte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the top of the CSS and put "* {width: 100%}". If that doesn't work, you might have to manually change the width until it fits the size of your viewport.

Comment: adding "* {width: 100%}" did not make any difference

Comment: I deleted the code you wrote and tried it again and now it's working somehow. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Change the footer CSS width unit from vw to %:

```
footer {
    background: var(--main-color);
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px 0;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: but i need the background color of the footer to be the full width of the screen

Answer (score 0):

```css
:root {
--main-color: #ff9955ff;
--secondary-color: yellow;
--dark-color: #444;
--light-color: #fafafa;
}
body {
font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
background: var(--light-color);
color: var(--dark-color);
text-align: justify;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
align-items: center;
padding: 10px;
font-size: 18px;
}

#svelte {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
flex-wrap: wrap;
align-content: center;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
}
::selection {
background: var(--main-color);
color: var(--light-color);
}

a {
text-decoration: none;
color: var(--dark-color);
}
input {
box-sizing: border-box;
}

.box {
background: red;
height: 100px;
width: 100px;
}
.center-text {
text-align: center;
}
.columns-two,
.columns-three,
.columns-four,
.columns-six {
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
align-items: center;
align-content: center;
justify-content: center;
gap: 30px;
}
.columns-two div {
width: clamp(480px, 480px, 100%);
}
.columns-three div {
width: clamp(200px, calc((1000px - (30px * 2)) / 3), 100%);
}
.columns-four div {
width: calc((1000px - (30px * 3)) / 4);
}
.columns-six div {
width: calc((1000px - (30px * 5)) / 6);
}
.horizontal {
display: flex;
align-items: center;
align-content: center;
justify-content: center;
gap: 20px;
}

.max-height {
min-height: 100vh;
}
.half-height {
min-height: calc(100vh / 2);
}
.max-width {
width: clamp(200px, 90vw, 1000px);
}
.vertical {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
align-items: center;
align-content: center;
justify-content: center;
}
.wrap {
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
}

/* header */
.header {
height: 70px;
justify-content: space-between;
}
.title {
height: 100%;
}
.title img {
height: 100%;
width: clamp(0px, 250px, 60%);
}
.nav-toggle-checkbox,
.nav-toggle-spans {
position: fixed;
top: 2.5%;
right: -100vw;
height: clamp(10px, 80px, 20vw);
width: clamp(10px, 80px, 20vw);
}
.nav-toggle-checkbox {
opacity: 0;
}
.nav-toggle-spans span {
height: 20%;
background: var(--main-color);
margin: 10% 0;
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
z-index: 2;
transition: 400ms;
}
.navbar {
display: flex;
gap: 2.5px;
transition: 300ms;
}
.navbar a {
margin: 5px;
}

/* footer */
footer {
background: var(--main-color);
width: 100vw;
padding: 20px 0;
text-align: center;
}
.socials {
gap: 10px;
}
footer img {
height: 50px;
width: 50px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
.nav-toggle-checkbox,
.nav-toggle-spans {
    right: 5%;
    transition: 400ms;
}
.nav-toggle-spans {
    z-index: 2;
}
.nav-toggle-checkbox {
    z-index: 3;
}
.nav-toggle-checkbox:checked ~ .nav-toggle-spans span {
    background: var(--light-color);
    transition: 400ms;
}
.nav-toggle-checkbox:checked ~ .nav-toggle-spans .nav-span-one {
    position: relative;
    top: 30%; /* Changed from 100% */
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    transition: 400ms;
}
.nav-toggle-checkbox:checked ~ .nav-toggle-spans .nav-span-two {
    opacity: 0;
}
.nav-toggle-checkbox:checked ~ .nav-toggle-spans .nav-span-three {
    position: relative;
    top: -30%;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transition: 400ms;
}
.navbar,
.nav-toggle-checkbox:not(:checked) ~ .navbar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: -100vh;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    background: var(--main-color);
    opacity: 90%;
    border-left: 4px solid var(--secondary-color);
    padding: 150px 5% 0 50px;
    z-index: 1;
    transition: 400ms;
}
.nav-toggle-checkbox:checked ~ .navbar {
    right: 0;
    transition: 400ms;
}
.nav-toggle-checkbox:checked ~ .navbar a {
    color: var(--light-color);
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 1.25em;
}
}
```

```html
<body tabindex="-1">
<div id="svelte">

    <body>
        <div class="max-width">
            <header class="header horizontal">
                <div class="title"><img loading="lazy" src="./logo-title.svg" alt="Title"></div> <input type="checkbox" class="nav-toggle-checkbox">
                <div class="nav-toggle-spans"><span class="nav-span-one"></span> <span class="nav-span-two"></span> <span class="nav-span-three"></span></div>
                <nav class="navbar"><a href="/">Home</a> <a href="elements">Elements</a> <a href="services">Services</a> <a href="contact">Contact</a></nav>
            </header>
            <!--<Header>-->

            <head>
                <title>Home - CSS Templates</title>
            </head>
            <section class="vertical">
                <h2>2 Columns</h2>
                <div class="wrap columns-two">
                    <div>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
                            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Amet luctus
                            venenatis lectus magna fringilla urna porttitor rhoncus dolor. Nisi quis
                            eleifend quam adipiscing vitae proin sagittis nisl. Ipsum dolor sit amet
                            consectetur adipiscing. Eu consequat ac felis donec et odio pellentesque
                            diam. Volutpat commodo sed egestas egestas fringilla phasellus faucibus
                            scelerisque. Sem et tortor consequat id porta nibh venenatis cras. Sed
                            faucibus turpis in eu mi bibendum neque egestas congue. Etiam non quam
                            lacus suspendisse faucibus interdum posuere lorem. Malesuada fames ac
                            turpis egestas maecenas pharetra. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
                            consectetur. Ut enim blandit volutpat maecenas volutpat blandit aliquam
                            etiam erat. Id aliquet risus feugiat in ante metus.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
                            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Amet luctus
                            venenatis lectus magna fringilla urna porttitor rhoncus dolor. Nisi quis
                            eleifend quam adipiscing vitae proin sagittis nisl. Ipsum dolor sit amet
                            consectetur adipiscing. Eu consequat ac felis donec et odio pellentesque
                            diam. Volutpat commodo sed egestas egestas fringilla phasellus faucibus
                            scelerisque. Sem et tortor consequat id porta nibh venenatis cras. Sed
                            faucibus turpis in eu mi bibendum neque egestas congue. Etiam non quam
                            lacus suspendisse faucibus interdum posuere lorem. Malesuada fames ac
                            turpis egestas maecenas pharetra. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
                            consectetur. Ut enim blandit volutpat maecenas volutpat blandit aliquam
                            etiam erat. Id aliquet risus feugiat in ante metus.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
            <!--<ColumnsTwo>-->
            <section class="vertical max-height">
                <h2>3 Columns</h2>
                <div class="wrap columns-three">
                    <div>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
                            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Amet luctus
                            venenatis lectus magna fringilla urna porttitor rhoncus dolor. Nisi quis
                            eleifend quam adipiscing vitae proin sagittis nisl. Ipsum dolor sit amet
                            consectetur adipiscing. Eu consequat ac felis donec et odio pellentesque
                            diam. Volutpat commodo sed egestas egestas fringilla phasellus faucibus
                            scelerisque. Sem et tortor consequat id porta nibh venenatis cras. Sed
                            faucibus turpis in eu mi bibendum neque egestas congue.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
                            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Amet luctus
                            venenatis lectus magna fringilla urna porttitor rhoncus dolor. Nisi quis
                            eleifend quam adipiscing vitae proin sagittis nisl. Ipsum dolor sit amet
                            consectetur adipiscing. Eu consequat ac felis donec et odio pellentesque
                            diam. Volutpat commodo sed egestas egestas fringilla phasellus faucibus
                            scelerisque. Sem et tortor consequat id porta nibh venenatis cras. Sed
                            faucibus turpis in eu mi bibendum neque egestas congue.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
                            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Amet luctus
                            venenatis lectus magna fringilla urna porttitor rhoncus dolor. Nisi quis
                            eleifend quam adipiscing vitae proin sagittis nisl. Ipsum dolor sit amet
                            consectetur adipiscing. Eu consequat ac felis donec et odio pellentesque
                            diam. Volutpat commodo sed egestas egestas fringilla phasellus faucibus
                            scelerisque. Sem et tortor consequat id porta nibh venenatis cras. Sed
                            faucibus turpis in eu mi bibendum neque egestas congue.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
            <!--<ColumnsThree>-->
            <section class="vertical">
                <hr>
                <h2>4 Columns</h2>
                <div class="wrap columns-four">
                    <div class="box"></div>
                    <div class="box"></div>
                    <div class="box"></div>
                    <div class="box"></div>
                </div>
                <hr>
            </section>
            <!--<ColumnsFour>-->
            <section class="vertical">
                <hr>
                <h2>6 Columns</h2>
                <div class="wrap columns-six">
                    <div class="box"></div>
                    <div class="box"></div>
                    <div class="box"></div>
                    <div class="box"></div>
                    <div class="box"></div>
                    <div class="box"></div>
                </div>
                <hr>
            </section>
            <!--<ColumnsSix>-->
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
                incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Amet luctus venenatis lectus
                magna fringilla urna porttitor rhoncus dolor. Nisi quis eleifend quam
                adipiscing vitae proin sagittis nisl. Ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur
                adipiscing. Eu consequat ac felis donec et odio pellentesque diam. Volutpat
                commodo sed egestas egestas fringilla phasellus faucibus scelerisque. Sem et
                tortor consequat id porta nibh venenatis cras. Sed faucibus turpis in eu mi
                bibendum neque egestas congue. Etiam non quam lacus suspendisse faucibus
                interdum posuere lorem. Malesuada fames ac turpis egestas maecenas pharetra.
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur. Ut enim blandit volutpat maecenas
                volutpat blandit aliquam etiam erat. Id aliquet risus feugiat in ante metus.</p>
    </body>
    <div id="svelte-announcer" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true" class="s-jHz34e3aRDB7"></div>
</div>

<footer>
    <p class="socials"><a href="www.facebook.com" target="_blank"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/fb/Facebook_icon_2013.svg" alt="facebook"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <a href="www.facebook.com" target="_blank"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/fb/Facebook_icon_2013.svg" alt="facebook"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <a href="www.facebook.com" target="_blank"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/fb/Facebook_icon_2013.svg" alt="facebook"></a>
    </p>
    <p>This website was designed by <a href="google.com">Name</a></p>
</footer>
</body>
```

Comment: Put the <footer> outside the main div "max-width" and display flex to the #svelte wrapper